# Connectionstring from docker container to SQL Server dblocal in host

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, docker, asp.net-core

We have a webserver running in an linux docker container. When I run it on a Windows 10 host I get following error on connecting to the local SQL Server:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SqlServerQueryCompilationContextFactory[1]
  An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query.
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid) ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException: No such device or address...
```

The connection string in the json looks like this:

```
"ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyAppDb;User ID=test;Password=test;",
```

When I debug the webserver in Visual Studio with the same connection string, it works. So I don't understand, why docker throws the `Connection string is not valid` error.

The webserver uses .NET Core 1.1, so regarding to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10920#issuecomment-240798358) connecting to a named instance of SQL Server should function. I have two SQL Server instances installed. Connection with named pipes won't work, because the linux docker doesn't support it.

I use the network mode host for the container, so it should have the same network environment as the host computer:

```
docker run --rm -it --name MyApp -v c:\users\myself\MyApp.json:/app/appsettings.json --network="host" MyAppImage
```

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Is [`LocalDb`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx) installed on the web server?

Comment: The container is on a different IP, not on the localhost, so if you are running the db server on the local machine, you need to enable TCP/IP networking for the database server, as well as update your configuration to use the HOSTNAME or IP of the host environment... this should ideally come in via an environment variable.

Comment: @DavidG: The LocalDb runs on the Windows 10 host machine.

Comment: @Tracker1: You are right, but I can't find a way to connect to localdb via IP/HOSTNAME, so I will use my other SQL Server instance for the DB.

Comment: You need to enable TCP in the configuration settings... I forget the name of the program.. then you can use HOST_IP for the IP, and the port should be default.  The container is a different IP from the host.  Also, you'll need to enable it for firewall access, as that may be restricted as well.

Answer (score 2):

> I use the network mode host for the container, so it should have the same network environment as the host computer

If I understand this statement correctly, this doesn't do what you think it does. The container has the same network environment as the host. However, the *host* isn't your physical machine, it's the VM that Docker creates to run Linux containers. There is a more comprehensive explanation of Hyper-V networking [here](http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/the-hyper-v-virtual-switch-explained-part-1/). *The diagram below is based on the one from that article*

[image: Docker on windows networking]

The network card outlined in red is the one that your machine uses to connect to the virtual switch Docker for Windows creates. Network card outlined in blue is the one the linux VM uses to connect to the same virtual switch. It's also the card that your container sees when it's using *host* networking.

When your application is running in a container, you need to connect to the database over the network. [This article](https://blog.docker.com/2016/09/build-your-first-docker-windows-server-container/) talks about building multi-container applications using Docker Compose on Windows. Although the author is using Windows containers, he provides an example [docker-compose file](https://github.com/friism/MusicStore/blob/master/docker-compose.windows.yml) that creates database container and a web container and connection string for linking them together.

There is also a great step by step walkthrough of dockerizing NerdDinner application. [Part 2](https://blog.sixeyed.com/dockerizing-nerd-dinner-part-2-connecting-asp-net-to-sql-server/) walks through converting the application from using `localdb` to a containerized SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for the insight regarding the host. Then it's clear, that I need to connect via IP or hostname as @Tracker1 suggested. Regarding the containerization of the SQL Server we don't want that in this scenario.